# selenium window_handle is null when dropdown is selected or clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, drop-down-menu, nightwatch.js

This is a conventional dropdown that is clicked or selected normally in other browsers... but for some reason in Safari, when I click or select it, I can't do anything else within the session and eventually it times out...

In more detail, actions and the symptom of the issue stated above:

1.) selecting an option in the dropdown, the options do not close and I am unable to click, or perform any other action on the page.
2.) when clicking on the dropdown and attempting to find then click on a option, selenium throws element not found.

below is some of the code:

Clicking the option directly:

```
const selector = 'dropDownId option[value="1"]';
this.click(selector);
```

Expanding the dropdown, then clicking the option:

```
this.click(dropDownId, () => {
  this.click('option[value="1"]');
});
```

Selecting an option using setValue:

```
this.setValue(dropDownId, 'someOptionString');
```

I noticed I lose the window_handle, which is probably the reason of my issues, but I am not sure why... the way I noticed it is by logging the following before and after the interaction with the dropdown:

```
console.log(window_handles);
```

Note any interaction with the same dropdown works fine in other browsers, Safari is the only one that doesn't.

Safari browser version: 11
Selenium Driver: 3.4.0
Test framework used: Nightwatch
App: React + Redux

Comment: Any reason to use `option[value="1"]` instead of handling through `select` ?

Comment: what do you mean exactly?